# Error code 87 with RegEnumValue

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I am trying to show a single value's name using RegEnumValue (I can use RegGetValue, but i'm trying to learn how to use the RegEnumValue function), but I'm getting the error code 87, "The parameter is incorrect".

Here's my code:

```
int wmain()
{
    //RegOpenKeyEx
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"WinSide";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_QUERY_VALUE;
    HKEY pkOpenResult;

    //RegEnumValue
    DWORD index = 0;
    WCHAR valueName[16383];
    LPWSTR pValueName = valueName;
    DWORD size=sizeof(valueName);
    DWORD reserved = NULL;
    DWORD type;
    WCHAR data[255];
    LPWSTR pData=data;
    DWORD sizeData = sizeof(data);

    LONG openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKey, options, samDesired, &pkOpenResult);

    if (openKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error opening the key. Code: %li\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Key opened!\n");

        LONG enumValue = RegEnumValue(pkOpenResult, index, pValueName, &size,
                                        &reserved, &type, pData, &sizeData);

        if (enumValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", enumValue);
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Going to show the value's name here!");
        }

        RegCloseKey(pkOpenResult);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

So sorry for any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpReserved` must be `NULL` as stated in the documentation. You pass a non-null value. That is the reason for the failure. Remove the `reserved` variable and simply pass `NULL` for `lpReserved`.

The `lpcchValueName` argument specifies characters rather than bytes. You pass the number of bytes in error. That mistake won't necessarily hurt you now but there is a buffer overrun error in the making there so you do need to fix it.

Comment: So... can I also create the `reserved` as a pointer to `NULL`, right? And `size` would be something like `DWORD size=wcslen(valueName);` Am I right?

Comment: Why is `options` wrong? The MSDN article says: "Set this parameter to zero or the following". I am not working with a symbolic link

Comment: Pass NULL. Don't use wcslen. It's the length of the buffer. 2001.

Comment: I am sory, David, but I don't get it. How do I correctly determine and set the size of the buffer, in characters? 

Is `options` wrong, also?

Comment: Since you are using static arrays, you can use `sizeof(valueName)/sizeof(valueName[0])` or `ARRAYSIZE(valueName)` to get the size in characters.  Also, you are using `WCHAR` for the `data[]` array, but `RegEnumValue()` can return value types other than strings. You should use `BYTE` instead for the `data[]` array (with adequate byte size), and then type-cast the `data[]` value based on the returned `type` value. Consider using [`RegQueryInfoKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902.aspx) to determine max buffer sizes and then allocate accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @RemyLebeau. The problem is that I cannot assign `lpcMaxValueNameLen` as the `valueName` size, like `valueName[lpcMaxValueNameLen]`. Do I have to use `malloc`?

Comment: @Checho yes, you would have to allocate dynamically, eg: `WCHAR *valueName = (WCHAR*) malloc((lpcMaxValueNameLen+1)*sizeof(WCHAR)); ... free(valueName);`